# Consider defining a bean of type 'UserConverter' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I don't know what happend with my spring boot application but now I can't to start it because of an error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Field userConverter in webapp.controllers.UserResourceController required a bean of type 'webapp.converter.UserConverter' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'webapp.converter.UserConverter' in your configuration.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Controller code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class UserResourceController {

@Autowired
private UserServiceImpl userService;

@Autowired
private UserConverter userConverter;

@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> addUser(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
    userService.persist(userConverter.toUser(userDto));
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(userDto);
}

@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<UserDto>> findAllUsers() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userConverter.toUserDtos(userService.getAll()));
}

@PutMapping("/api/user/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> updateUser(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
    User user = userConverter.toUser(userDto);
    user.setId(id);
    userService.persist(user);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(userDto);
}

@GetMapping("/api/user/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> findUser (@PathVariable Long id) {
    Optional<User> user = Optional.ofNullable(userService.getByKey(id));
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userConverter.toUserDto(user.get()));
}
}
```

The mapper class:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
@Service
public abstract class UserConverter {
    public abstract User toUser(UserDto userDto);
    public abstract UserDto toUserDto(User user);
    public abstract List<UserDto> toUserDtos(List<User> users);
}
```

The first I tried to run it without `@Service` annotation, and then with it annotation but I always see the same error.

Comment: only abstract class for converter class or I can't inject abstract class?

Comment: Are you actually running the MapStruct generator? Look in your `target` or output directory for a `.class` file. (Note that unless you have a compelling reason, you should use interfaces instead of abstract classes, but that's not your problem.)

Comment: file .class in my target directory, I use - <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: and I tried to use interface but the problem was the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You couldn't inject an abstract class which doesn't have any real implementation. It isn't possible in Java even without Spring. So have do you expect it could be injected?

I don't understand why do you need to inject that class. The best solution will create a utility class with the appropriate converter, like:

```
public final class UserConverter {
    private UserConverter() {}

    public static UserDTO toUserDTO(User employee) {
        Department empDp = employee.getDepartment();
        return UserDTO.builder()
                .id(employee.getId())
                .name(employee.getName())
                .active(employee.getActive())
                .departmentId(empDp.getId())
                .departmentName(empDp.getName())
                .build();
    }

    public static User toUser(UserDTO dto) {
        Department dp = Department.builder()
                .id(dto.getDepartmentId())
                .name(dto.getDepartmentName())
                .build();
        return User.builder()
                .id(dto.getId())
                .name(dto.getName())
                .active(dto.getActive())
                .department(dp)
                .build();
    }
}
```

And call it as a static method from your code:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> findUser (@PathVariable Long id) {
    return userService.getByKey(id)
            .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
            .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}
```

Also, your code has some mistakes for your API:

- mapping to resource should be plural like `@RequestMapping("/api/users")` -> and only when you need operation by id add `@GetMapping("/{id}")`
- create method should return `201 - Create` status code instead of **200**
- if `/api` should be common for all your API you could define it at the configuration file for all your resources.
  Snippet from `applicatoin.yml`:

  server:
    servlet:
      context-path: /api

***Useful references for solutions with MapStruct:***

- [Quick Guide to MapStruct](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct)
- [Automating Code with MapStruct](https://medium.com/@swathisprasad/automating-code-with-mapstruct-44b8c324a23e)

Comment: OK, but why was MapStruсt created then? I don’t want to write the converter implementation myself, so I use this library, may be you (or anyone) know how to use it correctly?

Comment: Mapping fixed thank you! But about MapStruct is actual question :)